# swap partition on extended partition?

Tags: arch-linux

Can I have my swap partition on my extended partition ?

Host operating system is arch Linux

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=900126.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter much whether you use a primary partition or an extended partition, or even a LVM, for swap. (Keep in mind that a MBR disk is limited to 4 primary partitions.) What matters more is the partition's position relative to other partitions, if you foresee to resize it one day.